# How to integrate CHGCAR data of VASP, in z-direction and have xy-plane charge density at each grid point on xy-plane?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, vesta

i asked this query in another [forum](http://henkelmanlab.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15594&sid=b2b074f9ca473c616a04df3979c20eb2), waiting for answer. However, also posting it here.

i got a CHGCAR file written for both optimised and non-optimised (single point run) runs of a lattice model.
So, i have two CHGCAR files.
Using vaspkit i did charge density difference subtracting from say, Optimised CHGCAR minus non-optimised CHGCAR, giving raise to another similar formatted **CHGDIFF.vasp** file.
Now, i wish to create a 2D plot to show the integrated charge density values along z-direction at each xy-plane grid point. To explain more, say the XY-plane has 40x34 grid, and Z-side has 120 grid.  Now i want the CHGDIFF.vasp values to be manipulated so that all values along z-grid are added up to finally written at xy-plane grid. Hope i am clear to you.

Assuming the option '315' in vaspkit will do whatever i wanted above, i run the option, gave input of this CHGDIFF.vasp. The vaspkit asked two values in 'a' and 'b' directions. not clear what these values for (could not locate in vaspkit documentation), i gave '1 and 1'.

Then it gave three **.grd** format files. I could not open these files in VESTA, moreover, when i try in, the VESTA is shutting down each time. I could not open these files in Material studio also.
Can anyone help to understand How to do such integration either with vaspkit and open these data for final 2D visualisation? or otherwise do some 'numerical computation' and then visualise in VESTA?

Comment: +1 but please show us a link to the question on the other forum too!

Comment: Try having a look at [this] (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6225/how-to-process-electron-density-data-from-a-chgcar-for-better-handling?rq=1). I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but once you have the CHG as a 3d array, you can do pretty much any processing you want, including selecting an XY plane at a certain Z and summing all the others.
As for the final display, considering that it is volumetric data, I think VESTA is not the best software for reprocessed data, unless you use the built-in functions on the original file (Utilities > 2D Data Display)

Comment: @NikeDattani here is the link. They responded a reply too. But not sure if i can proceed with it, as per my resources on coding. 
http://henkelmanlab.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15594&sid=b2b074f9ca473c616a04df3979c20eb2

Comment: @Salvios yes saw this link before, and i posted my query only after reading this link. My worry is more, like you said, after doing that re-processed data whether i could visualise the 2D plots in VESTA or not.  
as i asked in my main query, any clue how can view these .grd (i.e. grid files) in VESTA?

Comment: Hi @skm, in case you don't want to deal with programming, are you aware of the possibility to perform operations on chg data (sum, differences, etc.) directly in vesta (Edit > volumetric data) ? It should be simple and guaranteed to display the results in VESTA itself, as well as integration (Utilities > 2d data visualization).

Comment: hi @Salvios thank you for the reply. 
Yes i am aware of using sum, difference etc of volumetric data. 
But where is the option for integration? i have checked again in VESTA. i saw an integration called 'Voronoi' integration. That is not what i needed. I could not find any other integration in VESTA operation, please. Are you talking about something else than what i seen?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I confused 2D slicing functionality for integration. Isn't using python a possibility? You would solve the problem very quickly and could generate a contour plot. For visualization in VESTA, I wouldn't know how that would be possible at this point since it works mainly with volumetric and/or slice data. I could write you a small script in python as an answer if you want.

Comment: @Salvios thank you for your reply. Due to some technical and computational resources issues, currently cant do any coding, and even if i wish to do it would take quite some time. But if an already written code is there like xxx.py code. May be i can execute. If you help in this regard, it may be very nice and will also be useful for all the members of this forum. Thank you. Please send the script. I need z-direction integrated CHGCAR file revealing XY-plane charge density values of each grid on XY-plane. Hope i am clear to you. i.e. like a 2D sliced colored data in VESTA. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @skm, does the integration need to be performed for each XY plane or for a certain user-defined value ? I'll post the code as an answer as soon as i'll be back to the office (about a week). Is your cell orthogonal ? If not, care should be taken when plotting the map on a grid in order to avoid distortions.

Comment: @Salvios . Thanks for reply. I do not need integration for each XY-plane. Let me explain more and my exact problem (model). I have a hexagonal based crystal but the Z-axis is orthogonal. Means only the base face (i.e. XY-plane) is hexagonal.  now my crystal base lattice as per CHGCAR file is Lattice parameters

   a        b        c       alpha    beta     gamma
 6.52700  6.52900 10.00000  90.0000  90.0000 120.0000

Unit-cell volume = 369.054860 Å^3

Comment: Now i want the entire Z-axis be integrated and only the XY-plane grid CHGCAR to be shown. its exactly similar to the figure we get in 2D display of a slice colored plot. but in my case all the Xs, Ys, and Zs are summed up (integrated) over Z-axis (from Z=0 to Z=10, because Zmax=10)